# How does ignore affect interactions with team mates?

Tags: league-of-legends

Sometimes I'm forced to ignore someone on my team for some reason.  Can a player I've ignored still see my chat/pings?  Can I see their mini-map [pings](http://www.spugnort.com/2011/12/league-of-legends-map-awareness-mias-and-pings/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They can still see everything you say in chat, and all of your minimap pings unless they ignore you as well. You will no longer be able to see their minimap pings.

The commands to ignore someone for a single match is: (entered into chat)

```
/mute playerName
```

To ignore someone permanently:

```
/ignore playerName
```

---

Sources: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/V1.0.0.86 under 'General' for minimap pings.
http://na.leagueoflegends.com/learn/chat_commands for ignore commands.

Comment: He's not asking about latencey; he's asking about minimap pings.

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure about map pings.

Comment: Personal experience, and I've just cited a source for minimap pings. I wasn't sure about those.

Comment: As of the time this question was asked and answered, you could not see their pings, but they could see your chat/pings.  They made a change in Feb 2013, and now you see someone's pings even if you have them muted/ignored.  They tried to compensate for this by adding a "ping limiter" which stops them from pinging more than 3-4 times in a row.  Unfortunately, you still get people who will ping random things 3-4 times rapidly every time they're able to.